# Can I compile libpqxx to run on iOS and Android?

Tags: sql, windows, postgresql, unreal-engine4, libpqxx

I developing a game in Unreal and want to use Postgres as a backend.  the only information I can find as to what platforms libpqxx can be compiled for is that "...access databases managed by postgres—**on just about any platform**—then libpqxx is the library you use".  Does anybody know if it will compile to iOS and Android?  If not, can somebody recommend another database I can interface with in C++ that i can use with mobile devices?

Comment: You want to write a game in C++? Unless C++ is your requirement, use libpq. It is guaranteed to be high quality, up to date and offers the full power of PostgreSQL.

Comment: Unreal Engine is C++, which makes it a requirement.  libpq is a C library, could I just use that anyway?  I just need it to be compatible with visual studio 2017 compiler.  What's the point of libpqxx if libpq is already a c library? I also know c++ much better than I could also use a different database.  Do you have any recommendations of ones i could work with in c++, that would run on mobile?

Comment: No idea about mobile devices, you'd have to try it. The point of libpqxx is that it offers an object oriented interface. If you don't need that and are happy to talk plain C to the database, use libpq by all means.

Comment: I'll look into it and get back to you! in case it works, leave libpq as an answer and i'll mark it as solved!